# Extract function code from c sourcecode file with python

Tags: python, c, parsing

i am searching for a way to parse a c-source file in Python.

I know that there is a library like pycparse which can parse c-files but it seems that it depends on the gcc compiler.

I am working on a tool like readelf which reads a ELF file, extract the opcodes from a function. I need to read the c-sourcefiles to fetch the corresponding c-code of the function from the file.

So if we think on a split screen, i want to see the assembler/opcodes on the left, and the corresponding c-code on the right.

So for example, when i open a basic calculator writen in c, i have a function called "add" in my binary. I extract the opcodes/assembler and show it up on the left side of the window. Now i need a python function which opens all c-files in a directory to find the corresponding c-code of the function.

Anyone have a idea how to solve this challenge?

Here is a example-output of the stuff i have now:

```
|==================================================================|
| Adress             | Function                       | Size       |
|====================|================================|============|
| 0x000000000000065a | sub                            | 31         |
|==================================================================|
| 55 48 89 e5 89 7d ec 89 75 e8 c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 8b 45 ec 2b   |
| 45 e8 89 45 fc 8b 45 fc 5d c3                                    |
|==================================================================|
| int sub(int a, int b)                                            |
| {                                                                |
|   int c = 0;                                                     |
|   c = a - b;                                                     |
|   return c;                                                      |
| }                                                                |
|==================================================================|
```

But my code currently can only work with pycparse and basic-c-files because pycparse fails if i have to search in different c-files for the function. I think it uses the compiler to compile the code and just acts like a wrapper arround gcc.

Comment: checkout godbolt.org

Comment: It seems that you may use debug symbols instead.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small function to extract the function body from a c-source using ctags and python my self now.

Maybe it helps someone...

```
import subprocess
import glob


def get_line_number(filename, funcname):
    found = False
    cmd = "ctags -x --c-kinds=fp " + filename + " | grep " + funcname

    output = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
    lines = output.splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(funcname + " "):    
            found = True

            if output.strip() is not "":
                output = output.split(" ")
                lines = list(filter(None, output))
                line_num = lines[2]

                print("Function found in file " + filename + " on line: " + line_num)
                return int(line_num)

    if found == False:
        #print("Function not found")
        return 0


def process_file(filename, line_num):
    print("opening " + filename + " on line " + str(line_num))

    code = ""
    cnt_braket = 0
    found_start = False
    found_end = False

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if(i >= (line_num - 1)):
                code += line

                if line.count("{") > 0:
                    found_start = True
                    cnt_braket += line.count("{")

                if line.count("}") > 0:
                    cnt_braket -= line.count("}")

                if cnt_braket == 0 and found_start == True:
                    found_end = True
                    return code


folder = "/usr/src/bash-4.4.18"
funcname = "add_alias"

for filename in glob.iglob(folder + "/*.c", recursive=True):
    line_num = get_line_number(filename, funcname)

    if line_num > 0:
        process_file(filename, line_num)
```